# Integral boudaries when calculating expectations

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, expectation

Random variables $X_1,...X_n$ are independent and identically distributed with $X_1$ having the probability density function:

$$ f(x;\theta) = 3\theta^3 \frac{1}{x^4} \space for \space x>0 $$

Where $\theta>0$ Is an unknown parameter.

Then :

$$E[X_1]= 3\theta^3 \int_\theta^\infty x x^{-4} dx $$

**Why is the lower boundry of the integral $\theta$ and not $0$?**

Answer (score 0):

The definition of $f(x)$ should be for $x>\theta$ because $\int_{\theta}^{\infty}f(x)dx=1$.

Comment: yes, I was going to say the same.

Comment: Must be a typo in the exercise, nonethless we know that $\theta$ > 0, therefore could 0 be used for the lower boundry insted of the $\theta$ ?